Node.js Websocket closes with code 1001 (Going Away) after uploading from client
So I have a node.js Express server set up with secure websockets serving html, css and js files statically. It is working properly for what I needed until now.
I now want to add the ability to upload files from the client to the server. For this I added multer and set up the app.post like this:
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/dark/index.html', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('File uploaded:', req.file.originalname);

    // do some stuff with the file here

    res.sendStatus(200);
});

I then added a form to the HTML like this:
<form id="uploadFileForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Upload</button>
</form>

The form shows up and it seems like it's working fine as when I click on the "Choose File" button it does allow me to choose a file and the Upload button really does upload the file to the server.
My problem is not the actual upload, I think. It's what happens after. Because at the beginning I didn't have the res.sendStatus(200) line at the end of the app.post command. So the page in the browser looked like it was always loading (had the spinning thing in Chrome tab). But when I add the status 200, I'm redirected to a page that's just a black screen with the word "OK", which is the status, but the address doesn't actually change, and on the server side, it tells me that the websocket is closed with code 1001 which is going away, meaning it seems like the browser is going to a different address.
I've also tried to change res.sendStatus(200) to res.redirect('/dark/index.html') but it reloads the page to the start, where the user has to log back in again. Not what I wanted to happen.
I'd appreciate any help to understand why this is happening and what I can do to fix this. What I want to happen is to stay on the same page and not be redirected or have the websocket close on me.
Thanks
